# mysql select something as where is not null

Tags: php, mysql

I'm quite new at this, so I have question about MySQL. I have query in openCart:

```
$sql = "SELECT cp.category_id AS category_id,
           GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name
                        ORDER BY cp.level SEPARATOR '&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;') AS name,
           c1.parent_id,
           c1.sort_order
    FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c1 ON (cp.category_id = c1.category_id)
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c2 ON (cp.path_id = c2.category_id)
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd1 ON (cp.path_id = cd1.category_id)
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd2 ON (cp.category_id = cd2.category_id)
    WHERE cd1.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'
      AND cd2.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') ."'";
```

In MySQL I added new column "show_menu" (it can be NULL or 1) and now I want to change my query, that It will return only categories in where show_menu = 1

As I understand I need something like: WHERE show_menu IS 1. 
Maybe anyone can help where to put it? because I tried, but no luck...

Comment: And the of your query : Where show_menu like '1'

Comment: `is 1`? that's not going to work. why not `show_menu=1`?

Comment: simply use `where show_menu IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following to your WHERE clause:

... AND show_menu = 1

Just Like

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE conditions_from_your_existing_query
  AND show_menu = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `show_menu = 1` or `show_menu IS NOT NULL`

You just can't use the '=' operator with a null value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show_menu = 1` or you can use `show_menu is not null`. Either way will work.